# MvvmCross ShowViewModel method missing

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I followed the documentation on testing on the MvvmCross website. I'am able to register my mock dispatcher and everything works except when any of my view models executes `ShowViewModel`. This gives me a System.MissingMethodException.

My test class is a class library (.Net 4.5).

I have a WPF application, and everything works fine in there. But for some reason, my test class library gives me this problem. I've removed/reinstalled all NuGet packages, unchecked/checked all references to my PCL where the view models I'm testing are located.

1) Why am I getting this exception?

1.1) Could it be some dll that I'm missing?

2) Where is the actual concrete definition for `ShowViewModel`? The only reference I can find is in `MxvNavigationObject`, but that's an abstract class.

Comment: Fixed. See comment in Joagwa's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Viewmodel class (where I hope you are trying to call it) inheriting from MvxViewModel? as that is where the ShowViewModel method is (via MvxNavigatingObject)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;

namespace App1.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ShowViewModel(typeof(SecondViewModel));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is. I fixed the problem. It was a version issue with MvvmCross. I uninstalled v5.1.1 and installed 4.3.0, to match that of my PCL. Now it works.